# Will shubunkin and other fancy goldfish eat smaller fish in a pond?

Tags: fish, safety, introducing-pets, goldfish, pond

I am building a 20,000 gallon (76,000 liters) backyard pond for some shubunkins and other fancy goldfish that have outgrown their aquarium. Our climate is such that the pond will only freeze occasionally, and with not much depth to the ice.

I'd like to add some large schools of smaller cold-temperature fish from the pet store, such as white mountain cloud minnows, cold-friendly corys, and other tiny fish that can withstand the cold, but these are 10% of the size of the average goldfish, and the goldfish will only get larger once put in the pond.

Will these smaller fish just become snacks, or can they live happily alongside these big goldfish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you can be sure the fish you add is 10% the size or more of the goldfish size, the goldfish will not eat the other fish.

Most smaller fish are good at protecting themselves from getting eaten, so as long as you give the smaller fish some hiding places, they will not get eaten.

I do not have goldfish in my pond, but I do have about 15 koi; they display the same behaviour as goldfish. I do not have any problems with the other types of fish in my pond getting eaten.

The fish types you add to your pond is a larger threat to your goldfish babies (if your goldfish spawn in your pond) than your goldfish is to your other fish.

If you want to add new types of fish to your pond it is best to do it now before your goldfish grow too large.